# Tutorial - Hello, World! Pt.2 Issue

Tags: corda

I tried to follow the second Hello World tutorial and got this error message, any advice?

`Cannot find contract attachments for com.template.IOUContractnull. See https://docs.corda.net/api-contract-constraints.html#debugging`

Looking at the tutorial answers in github, the source has numerous differences (possible bugs) to the instructions and the instructions seems to make more sense.

This compiles and deploys ok. When I try to create a new IOU, it fails to do so.

Thanks in advance

Here are my files:

**Flow.kt**

```
package com.template.flows

import co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Suspendable
import net.corda.core.contracts.Command
import net.corda.core.flows.*
import net.corda.core.identity.Party
import net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder
import net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker

import com.template.states.IOUState
import com.template.contracts.IOUContract
import net.corda.core.contracts.requireThat
import net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction

// *********
// * Flows *
// *********
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class IOUFlow(val iouValue: Int,
              val otherParty: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]

        val outputState = IOUState(iouValue, ourIdentity, otherParty)
        val command = Command(IOUContract.Create(), listOf(ourIdentity.owningKey, otherParty.owningKey))

        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)
                .addOutputState(outputState, IOUContract.ID)
                .addCommand(command)

        txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

        val signedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

        val otherPartySession = initiateFlow(otherParty)

        val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(signedTx, listOf(otherPartySession), CollectSignaturesFlow.tracker()))

        subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, otherPartySession))
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(IOUFlow::class)
class IOUFlowResponder(private val otherPartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        var signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherPartySession) {
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {
                val output = stx.tx.outputs.single().data
                "This must be an IOU transaction" using (output is IOUState)
                val iou = output as IOUState
                "IOU value can't be too high" using (iou.value < 100)

            }
        }
        val expectedTxId = subFlow(signTransactionFlow).id
        subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherPartySession, expectedTxId))
    }
}
```

**TemplateState.kt**

```
package com.template.states

import com.template.contracts.IOUContract
import net.corda.core.contracts.BelongsToContract
import net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState
import net.corda.core.identity.AbstractParty
import net.corda.core.identity.Party

// *********
// * State *
// *********
@BelongsToContract(IOUContract::class)

class IOUState(val value: Int,
               val lender: Party,
               val borrower: Party) : ContractState {
    override val participants get() = listOf(lender, borrower)
}
```

**TemplateContract.kt**

```
package com.template.contracts

import com.template.states.IOUState
import net.corda.core.contracts.CommandData
import net.corda.core.contracts.Contract
import net.corda.core.contracts.requireSingleCommand
import net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction
import net.corda.core.contracts.*

// ************
// * Contract *
// ************

class IOUContract : Contract {
    companion object {
        const val ID = "com.template.IOUContract"
    }

    class Create : CommandData

    override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
        val command = tx.commands.requireSingleCommand<Create>()

        requireThat {
            "No input when issue" using (tx.inputs.isEmpty())
            "One output of type IOUState" using (tx.outputs.size == 1)

            val output = tx.outputsOfType<IOUState>().single()
            "IOU's value must be non-negative" using (output.value > 0)
            "Borrower and lender can't be the same" using (output.lender != output.borrower)

            val expectedSigners = listOf(output.borrower.owningKey, output.lender.owningKey)
            "must be two signers" using (command.signers.toSet().size == 2)
            "both must be signers" using (command.signers.containsAll(expectedSigners))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue!

I think it is a bug in the instructions:
https://docs.corda.net/tut-two-party-contract.html

specifies: `const val ID = "com.template.IOUContract"`

where it should be: `const val ID = "com.template.contracts.IOUContract"`

:(

R3 should at least make instructions to their tutorials correct

Answer (score 0):

I think your node doesn't have the `contracts` jar file inside its `cordapps` folder.
I assume that you're running the tutorial locally (i.e. `deployNodes` then `runNodes`); make sure that your node (which is defined inside the root `build.gradle` file under task `deployNodes`) has the `contracts` module dependency (i.e. `cordapp project(":contracts")`).
Btw, I don't know the exact name of the `contracts` module in your example; make sure you get it right (gradle will give you an error anyway if it's not correct).

Comment: Thanks for assisting. https://github.com/corda/corda-tut2-solution-kotlin/blob/c6d38913a40a17224090c083b4099186de48daeb/build.gradle - This isn't very helpful - My deployNodes has: ```node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        p2pPort 10005
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10006")
            adminAddress("localhost:10046")
        }
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }```

Comment: and ```nodeDefaults {
        projectCordapp {
            deploy = false
        }
        cordapp project(':contracts')
        cordapp project(':workflows')
    }``` - which I believe includes contracts.

in `/build/nodes/PartyA/cordapps`, i have `contracts-0.1.jar`